How to use Async Redis Client + Django in python?
I'm trying to create a distributed semaphore using Redis to use in my Django application. This is to limit concurrent requests to an API. I'm using asyncio in redis-py. However, I want to create a connection pool to share across requests since I was getting a "Max clients reached" error. Thus, I created a shared connection pool in settings.py which I use in my semaphore class. However, I then get an error got Future <Future pending> attached to a different loop when I make concurrent requests. This is my code:
import os
import uuid
import asyncio
import time
from typing import Any
import random
from django.conf import settings
from redis import asyncio as aioredis

STARTING_BACKOFF_S = 4
MAX_BACKOFF_S = 16


class SemaphoreTimeoutError(Exception):
    """Exception raised when a semaphore acquisition times out."""

    def __init__(self, message: str) -> None:
        super().__init__(message)


class RedisSemaphore:
    def __init__(
        self,
        key: str,
        max_locks: int,
        timeout: int = 30,
        wait_timeout: int = 30,
    ) -> None:
        """
        Initialize the RedisSemaphore.

        :param redis_url: URL of the Redis server.
        :param key: Redis key for the semaphore.
        :param max_locks: Maximum number of concurrent locks.
        :param timeout: How long until the lock should automatically be timed out in seconds.
        :param wait_timeout: How long to wait before aborting attempting to acquire a lock.
        """
        self.redis_url = os.environ["REDIS_URL"]
        self.key = key
        self.max_locks = max_locks
        self.timeout = timeout
        self.wait_timeout = wait_timeout
        self.redis = aioredis.Redis(connection_pool=settings.REDIS_POOL)
        self.identifier = "Only identifier"

    async def acquire(self) -> str:
        """
        Acquire a lock from the semaphore.

        :raises SemaphoreTimeoutError: If the semaphore acquisition times out.
        :return: The identifier for the acquired semaphore.
        """
        czset = f"{self.key}:owner"
        ctr = f"{self.key}:counter"
        identifier = str(uuid.uuid4())
        now = time.time()
        start_time = now
        backoff = STARTING_BACKOFF_S

        while True:
            # TODO: Redundant?
            if time.time() - start_time > self.wait_timeout:
                raise SemaphoreTimeoutError("Waited too long to acquire the semaphore.")

            async with self.redis.pipeline(transaction=True) as pipe:
                pipe.zremrangebyscore(self.key, "-inf", now - self.timeout)
                pipe.zinterstore(czset, {czset: 1, self.key: 0})
                pipe.incr(ctr)
                counter = (await pipe.execute())[-1]

                pipe.zadd(self.key, {identifier: now})
                pipe.zadd(czset, {identifier: counter})
                pipe.zrank(czset, identifier)
                rank = (await pipe.execute())[-1]

                print(rank)
                if rank < self.max_locks:
                    return identifier

                pipe.zrem(self.key, identifier)
                pipe.zrem(czset, identifier)
                await pipe.execute()

            # Exponential backoff with randomness
            sleep_time = backoff * (1 + random.random() * 0.3)
            if (sleep_time + time.time() - start_time) > self.wait_timeout:
                raise SemaphoreTimeoutError("Waited too long to acquire the semaphore.")
            await asyncio.sleep(sleep_time)
            backoff = min(backoff * 2, MAX_BACKOFF_S)

    async def release(self, identifier: str) -> bool:
        """
        Release a lock from the semaphore.

        :param identifier: The identifier for the lock to be released.
        :return: True if the semaphore was properly released, False if it had timed out.
        """
        czset = f"{self.key}:owner"
        async with self.redis.pipeline(transaction=True) as pipe:
            pipe.zrem(self.key, identifier)
            pipe.zrem(czset, identifier)
            result = await pipe.execute()
        return result[0] > 0


class RedisSemaphoreContext:
    def __init__(self, semaphore: RedisSemaphore) -> None:
        """
        Initialize the RedisSemaphoreContext.

        :param semaphore: An instance of RedisSemaphore.
        """
        self.semaphore = semaphore
        self.identifier = None

    async def __aenter__(self) -> "RedisSemaphoreContext":
        """Enter the async context manager."""
        self.identifier = await self.semaphore.acquire()
        return self

    async def __aexit__(self, exc_type: Any, exc_val: Any, exc_tb: Any) -> None:
        """Exit the async context manager."""
        await self.semaphore.release(self.identifier)


Trace

  File "/Users/.../app/fetchers.py", line 313, in get_page_with_semaphore
    async with RedisSemaphoreContext(semaphore):
  File "/Users/.../app/redis_semaphore.py", line 123, in __aexit__
    await self.semaphore.release(self.identifier)
  File "/Users/.../app/redis_semaphore.py", line 102, in release
    result = await pipe.execute()
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/miniconda3/envs/cb-be/lib/python3.12/site-packages/redis/asyncio/client.py", line 1528, in execute
    return await conn.retry.call_with_retry(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/miniconda3/envs/cb-be/lib/python3.12/site-packages/redis/asyncio/retry.py", line 59, in call_with_retry
    return await do()
           ^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/miniconda3/envs/cb-be/lib/python3.12/site-packages/redis/asyncio/client.py", line 1371, in _execute_transaction
    await self.parse_response(connection, "_")
  File "/opt/miniconda3/envs/cb-be/lib/python3.12/site-packages/redis/asyncio/client.py", line 1464, in parse_response
    result = await super().parse_response(connection, command_name, **options)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/miniconda3/envs/cb-be/lib/python3.12/site-packages/redis/asyncio/client.py", line 633, in parse_response
    response = await connection.read_response()
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/miniconda3/envs/cb-be/lib/python3.12/site-packages/redis/asyncio/connection.py", line 541, in read_response
    response = await self._parser.read_response(
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/miniconda3/envs/cb-be/lib/python3.12/site-packages/redis/_parsers/resp2.py", line 82, in read_response
    response = await self._read_response(disable_decoding=disable_decoding)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/miniconda3/envs/cb-be/lib/python3.12/site-packages/redis/_parsers/resp2.py", line 90, in _read_response
    raw = await self._readline()
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/miniconda3/envs/cb-be/lib/python3.12/site-packages/redis/_parsers/base.py", line 219, in _readline
    data = await self._stream.readline()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/miniconda3/envs/cb-be/lib/python3.12/asyncio/streams.py", line 568, in readline
    line = await self.readuntil(sep)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/miniconda3/envs/cb-be/lib/python3.12/asyncio/streams.py", line 660, in readuntil
    await self._wait_for_data('readuntil')
  File "/opt/miniconda3/envs/cb-be/lib/python3.12/asyncio/streams.py", line 545, in _wait_for_data
    await self._waiter
RuntimeError: Task <Task pending name='Task-111' coro=<GeneralWebPageFetcher.async_get_pages.<locals>.get_page_with_semaphore() running at /Users/app/fetchers.py:313> cb=[gather.<locals>._done_callback() at /opt/miniconda3/envs/cb-be/lib/python3.12/asyncio/tasks.py:767]> got Future <Future pending> attached to a different loop


which I then use in my adrf async views.
What am I doing wrong? Is this possible?

Please add a error traceback so that we can better understand the problem you're facing.

@LukeL added a trace. Sorry about that.

Thanks, it helped. The error is quite an interesting one indeed. Seems like the awaits interfered with each other.

The answer turned out to be something completely unrelated. In fact, it was Django runserver that wasn't playing well with a mix of async and non-async endpoints. For some reason this only surfaced now when I shared a Redis connection pool via settings.py.
The fix was to run locally with uvicorn, which solved the issue. Another fix would've been to turn all the endpoints to async.
